# Mongodb create index for boolean and integer fields

Tags: mongodb

user collection

```
[{
        deleted: false,
        otp: 3435,
        number: '+919737624720',
        email: 'Test@gmail.com',
        name: 'Test child name',
        coin: 2
    },
    {
        deleted: false,
        otp: 5659,
        number: '+917406732496',
        email: 'anand.satyan@gmail.com',
        name: 'Nivaan',
        coin: 0
    }
    ]
```

I am using below command to create index Looks like for string it is working
But i am not sure this is correct for number and boolean field.

```
db.users.createIndex({name:"text", email: "text", coin: 1, deleted: 1})
```

I am using this command to filter data:

```
db.users.find({$text:{$search:"anand.satya"}}).pretty()
db.users.find({$text:{$search:"test"}}).pretty()
db.users.find({$text:{$search:2}}).pretty()
db.users.find({$text:{$search:false}}).pretty()
```

string related fields working. But numeric and boolean fields are not working.
Please check how i will create index for them

Comment: You have not specified any filters related to `coin` or `deleted` fileds.

Comment: How to specify this ? Can you please answer createIndex command ?

Comment: The `createIndex` command seems correct. What is the exact use case that you are targeting?

Comment: I wants to search by any of the field. name, email, coin, deleted
How can i search by coin and deleted

Comment: You'll have to convert your coin and deleted fields to string, if you want it to be picked up by $search

Comment: So. There is no way for searching boolean or integger field. ?

Comment: Nope, not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The title and comments in this question are misleading. Part of the question is more focused on how to query with fields that contain boolean and integer fields while another part of the question is focused on overall indexing strategies.

Regarding indexing, the index that was shown in the question is perfectly capable of satisfying some queries that include predicates on `coin` and `deleted`. We can see that when looking at the `explain` output for a query of `.find({$text:{$search:"test"}, coin:123, deleted: false})`:

```
> db.users.find({$text:{$search:"test"}, coin:123, deleted: false}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan.inputStage
{
  stage: 'FETCH',
  inputStage: {
    stage: 'IXSCAN',
    filter: {
      '$and': [ { coin: { '$eq': 123 } }, { deleted: { '$eq': false } } ]
    },
    keyPattern: { _fts: 'text', _ftsx: 1, coin: 1, deleted: 1 },
    indexName: 'name_text_email_text_coin_1_deleted_1',
    isMultiKey: false,
    isUnique: false,
    isSparse: false,
    isPartial: false,
    indexVersion: 2,
    direction: 'backward',
    indexBounds: {}
  }
}
```

Observe here that the index scan stage (`IXSCAN`) is responsible for providing the `filter` for the `coin` and `deleted` predicates (as opposed to the database having to do that after `FETCH`ing the full document.

Separately, you mentioned in the question that these two particular queries aren't working:

```
db.users.find({$text:{$search:2}}).pretty()
db.users.find({$text:{$search:false}}).pretty()
```

And by 'not working' you are referring to the fact that no results are being returned. This is also related to the following discussion in the comments which seemed to have a misleading takeaway:

> You'll have to convert your coin and deleted fields to string, if you want it to be picked up by $search – Charchit Kapoor
>
> So. There is no way for searching boolean or integger field. ? – Kiran S youtube channel
>
> Nope, not that I know of. – Charchit Kapoor

You *can* absolutely use boolean and integer values in your query predicate to filter data. [This playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5xrLUEfJjLP) demonstrates that.

What @Charchit Kapoor is mentioning that can't be done is using [the `$text` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) to match and return results whose field values are not strings. Said another way, the `$text` operator is specifically used to perform a text search.

If what you are trying to achieve are direct equality matches for the field values, both strings and otherwise, then you can delete the text index as there is no need for using the `$text` operator in your query. A simplified query might be:

```
db.users.find({ name: "test"})
```

Demonstrated in [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I0dtTr8OKFW).

A few additional things come to mind:

- Regarding indexing overall, databases will generally consider using an index if the first key is used in the query. You can read more about this for MongoDB specifically on [this page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/). The takeaway is that you will want to create the appropriate set of indexes to align with your most commonly executed queries. If you have a query that just filters on `coin`, for example, then you may wish to create an index that has `coin` as its first key.
- If you want to check if the exact string value is present in multiple fields, then you may want to do so using the `$or` operator (and have appropriate indexes for the database to use).
- If you do indeed need more advanced text searching capabilities, then it would be appropriate to either continue using the `$text` operator or consider Atlas Search if the cluster is running in Atlas. Doing so does not prevent you from also having indexes that would support your other queries, such as on `{ coin: 2 }`. It's simply that the syntax for performing such a query needs to be updated.

There is a lot going on here, but the big takeaway is that you can absolutely filter data based on any data type.  Doing so simply requires using the appropriate syntax, and doing so efficiently requires an appropriate indexing strategy to be used along side of the queries.